# Loop through multiple filters

Tags: arangodb, aql

Is there any possibility to write the following query in ArangoDB without using construction query from a string?

```
// get all records where all given constraints are not null

LET constraints = ["size", "color", "model"]
FOR x IN some_collection
  FOR c IN constraints
    FILTER x[c] != null
  RETURN x
```

this variant doesn't work unfortunately

**Update #1:**

I've managed to do this with the following dirty hack:

```
LET constraints = ["size", "color", "model"]
FOR xxx IN some_collection
  LET not_null_constraints = (
    FOR item IN constraints
      FILTER xxx[item] != null
      RETURN 1
  )
  FILTER length(not_null_constraints) == length(constraints)
  RETURN xxx
```

If there is any better approach, please, let me know

Comment: Sometimes it's faster to programmatically build the filter statement before executing it. Remember to protect yourself from SQL injection.

Comment: @DavidThomas can you answer with example? so, I will be able to choose best answer and close this one? )

Comment: You can ask ChatGPT to write Foxx code for you, it's amazingly good at it :)

Comment: @DavidThomas sometimes it produces output with outdated syntax, keywords, etc.